# Having problems redirecting stderr to a subshell created w/process substitution

Tags: bash, solaris-10, truss

```
~ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.10)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

The following command works as expected:

```
~ ls hdfhdfhdhfd 2> >(wc -l)
1
```

... but this doesn't work, and I'm running out of ideas to figure out why:

```
~ truss -eaf bash -c 'true' 2> >( some command to process text)
```

The command inside the `>()` ends up blocking waiting for input.

If I do this instead:

```
~ (true; truss -eaf bash -c 'true') 2> >( some command )
```

... it works as expected, though this doesn't work:

```
~ (      truss -eaf bash -c 'true') 2> >( some command )
#  ^^^^^ ... note the 1st command is missing
```

If I make `some command` = `dd bs=1`, it consumes and prints all text truss would've spat out on `stderr`, then blocks.

I cannot reproduce similar behavior in Linux, only when using `truss` in solaris.

Comment: Maybe some shell / default shell combination difference between Solaris and Linux box produces those different behaviors.

Comment: Maybe try using '-o' instead of redirection

Comment: ccarton, You should post that as an answer.  It does solve the problem, however I'm still very curious why this happens in the first place.  `truss` is the only terminal app I've seen this sort of behavior with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @ccarton's response I've come up with a rough idea of what's happening.  To illustrate:

```
~ truss -eaf /usr/bin/perl -e 'print "Test\n"; sleep 5' 2> >(dd bs=1 | wc -l)
```

In another terminal I could see this parent/child hierarchy:

1. `bash`

   1. `truss -eaf /usr/bin/perl -e printf "Test\n"; sleep 5`

      1. `/usr/bin/perl -e printf "Test\n"; sleep 5`
      2. `bash`

         1. `dd bs=1`

            1. `wc -l`

`truss` is waiting on the shell, but `dd` won't exit until its stdin is closed ... so they deadlock.

```
~ truss -eaf -o >(some command) another command
```

... causes `some command` to execute under the current shell so `truss` is never its ancestor.

I saw the same hierarchy in Linux, but it doesn't deadlock.